# Proof that $\frac{x}{y}\le \left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{x-y}$, $x\ge y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How can I prove that
$$\frac{x}{y}\le \left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{x-y}$$
for $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\ge y$?

It is reminiscent of Bernoulli's inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Bernoulli's inequality:
$$
\left(1+\frac1y\right)^{x-y}\ge 1+(x-y)\cdot\frac 1y=1+\frac xy-1=\frac xy.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Taking the first two terms of the Binomial Theorem,
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{x-y}\ge 1^{x-y}+\frac{x-y}y\cdot 1^{x-y-1}=\frac{x}{y}$$